# WPF: How to know if users clicked a Rectangle/Line/Ellipse which are drawn in Canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm doing MyPaint application.
Now I have some problem.

1. Users draw some shapes in canvas. Then they can select and move it by **click-drag and drop**. **So how to know if users clicked on a shapes (Outline or within the shapes)?**
2. As soon as they clicked on the shapes, a dash-stroke square and some anchor points will be shown (as the [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tg4CM.png)). Then users can click and keep pressing on those anchor point to **resize** the shapes. So how to design **Resize function like this**?

I have no idea about the code. Can anyone give me some hints?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps find some open source solutions that implement this, and examine how they do it?

Comment: I've found solution for a week and I gained no thing.

Comment: I'm sure if you read some ***basic*** WPF book and then google around ***just a bit***, you should find the right approach. Then you can try that approach yourself before asking any question here.

Comment: See https://youtu.be/T3jds4To7k4

Answer (score 0):

Finding out if the user has clicked on the shape could be as easy as implementing a MouseDown event handler on the shape (rectangle.MouseDown += ...). As far as moving and resizing, this example should be useful (you may have to calculate your own scale if you're only using the mouse but it should point you in the right direction):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee649090(v=vs.100).aspx